# Is loopback default login method using JWT as auth?

Tags: node.js, authorization, jwt, loopbackjs

I just want to make sure, what method loopback use to do an authorization in /login method?

is it JWT or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

Loopback use their own approach (non-jwt),a table is created in DB called AcessToken. when user login , a token is sent to user and stored in AcessToken Table used for the verification